# Proving a formula for k-th derivative of a given function.

Tags: real-analysis

For all $k\in\{0,1,2,...\}$ lets define $h_k(x)=x^{(k-1)}e^{1/x},\space x\neq 0$ and $H_k$ as k-th derivative of $h_k$. Prove that $H_k(x)=(-1)^kx^{-2k}h_k(x)$.

I tried to use Lebniz formula, but it didn't get me anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Notice that $h_{k}(x)=x\cdot h_{k-1}(x)$. Can you use this property in conjunction with complete induction to arrive at your desired result?

You should also use something along the lines of
$$
(h_{k+1}(x))^{(k+1)}=(x\cdot h_{k}(x))^{(k+1)}=(x\cdot h_{k}'(x)+h_{k}(x))^{(k)}=(x\cdot h_{k}'(x))^{(k)}+h_{k}(x)^{(k)}.
$$

It gets a little messy. I am not sure if there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Base case:

$$h^{(k)}_k(x) = (-1)^kx^{-2k}h_k(x) \text{ for k=0}$$

Inductive assumption:

$$h^{(k)}_k(x) = (-1)^kx^{-2k}h_k(x)$$

Inductive case:

$$h^{(k+1)}_{k+1}(x) = (-1)^{k+1}x^{-2(k+1)}h_{k+1}(x)$$

$${d\over dx}x h^{(k)}_k(x) = (-1)^{k+1}x^{-2(k+1)}h_{k+1}(x)$$

Apply definition of h and inductive assumption, cleanup...